# Can I use querySelector method in Blaze Template Instance

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I know the way that lookup DOM with jquery.

```
Template.foo.events({
  'click #bar'(eve, instance) {
    $('selector'); //A common way.
    instance.$('selector'); // Better performance.
    document.querySelector('selector'); // its good too
    instance.querySelector('selector'); // its not work
  }
})
```

I know that `instance` is not node type, so naturally `instance.querySelector('selector')` can't work!

But I want to use like `instance.$('selector')`.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
instance.find('selector')    --> querySelector
instance.findAll('selector') --> querySelectorAll
```

Note that these both use jQuery under the hood.

If you really want a true browser queryselector without a wrapper use:

```
instance.firstNode.querySelector('selector')
```